# Revert to show all when all filters are removed

Tags: jquery, find, show-hide

How can I get this function to revert to showing everything when all the filters are removed?

I've tried changing *`if (attrColor == 'All') {...}`* to *`if (attrColor == 'All' || attrColor == '') {...}`*

I've posted a fiddle with a simple example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/88/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrColor),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrColor);
        }
        if (attrColor == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } else {
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function(index,item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-color *="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can't see you fiddle working. getting :page can not be displayed on output section??

Comment: @Sangeeta - It's working fine on my computer, although I've only tried it in Firefox. Are you using another browser?

Answer (score 1):

See this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/97/)

```
if (attrColor == 'All' || !selected.length) {
    $('#content').find('*').show();
} else {
    $("#content").find("*").hide();
    $.each(selected, function (index, item) {
        $('#content').find('[data-color *="' + item + '"]').show();
    });
}
```

Edit:

Update as per @ArunPJohny's suggestion:

Using [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selector would be better than * selector to get the child `li`s

```
if (attrColor == 'All' || !selected.length) {
    $('#content').children().show();
} else {
    $("#content").children().hide();
    $.each(selected, function (index, item) {
        $('#content').find('[data-color *="' + item + '"]').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: As an additional suggestion, It is better not to use the selecot `*`, see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KnKYc/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Would you mind elaborating on why you recommend against using the * selector?

Comment: Both work well with one slight issue - How can I get it to behave the way the other elements do and remain active until it's unselected?

Comment: When any of the colors are 'checked' it returns those values until they're 'unchecked', but 'All Colors' is only remaining active until another color is checked